# How to make a custom private plugin in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Is there any way to achieve this? Everywhere I see contributing to plugin development or making use of an existing plugin (which are public). I would like to make a private plugin. Is this possible? I'm aware that through eclipse (for android) I can do this. But anyway to do this using phonegap build process so that I can make use of other advantages of using phonegap build?

Answer (score 8):

As of 9.Decemeber 2014, it's now possible to use custom private plugins in Phonegap build.

From Q2 2016 the private plugins appear to require a private Github repository. 
The following is stated in the FAQ https://build.phonegap.com/faq:

"Can I use PhoneGap Build with a private Github repository?

Yes! As of the most recent update to PhoneGap Build, you can now point the service at a private GitHub repository. Once your Build account is connected to your GitHub account in the user settings, you simply provide your authentication information and the Build service uses it when creating new builds of your code."

Comment: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins seems to be outdated. I cannot find a direct link to documentation how to make plugins **private**. Could you update the information?

Comment: @nacho4d updated the answer to reflect the new procedure

Comment: Thank you very much @dparnas

Answer (score 5):

For Phonegap Build, at this time there is not a method to create a private plugin. [See this article](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-contributing):

> Any plugins added to our system right now will be accessible to all
>   PhoneGap Build users; there may be other mechanisms for PhoneGap Build
>   plugin usage in the future.