# PhoneGap Build Exec Native Code

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Is it possible to invoke the following native Java statement from JavaScript using PhoneGap Build?

```
setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false)
```

A third party plugin (Stripe) depends on Android devices having this setting set to false in order to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can load [private plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656810/how-to-make-a-custom-private-plugin-in-phonegap), but there's no reason you can't create a public one and [submit it](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins) to phonegap build.

[Creating Custom Plugins](http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/en/manual/application/cordova_plugin/)

[importing plugins in phonegap build](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html)